# dict with unequal arrays into DataFrame and .csv in python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to put a dictionary with varying length string arrays into a pandas dataframe, and eventually into a .csv file.

I haven't been able to find documentation or examples on how to do this. There are a few that come close, but I am still getting a range of errors. I'd be more than happy of someone could point me in the right direction of an existing answer.

The dictionary that I want to import into a df is given to me like this:

> my_dict_A = {'a': ['0.130', '2', '2.000'], 'b': ['0.130', '1', '1.000'], 'c': ['0.130', '0.020'], 'v': ['1161.787', '1612.507'], 'p': ['0.132', '0.134'], 't': [2480, 3385], 'l': ['0.130', '0.130'], 'h': ['0.138', '0.138'], 'o': '0.136'}

I'm looking for the df (and csv) to look like the below:

```
|                                                                      A                                                                         |
|        a         |         b         |       c       |          v          |       p       |      t     |       l       |       h       |   o  |
|0.130 | 2 | 2.000 | 0.130 | 1 | 1.000 | 0.130 | 0.020 | 1161.787 | 1612.507 | 0.132 | 0.134 | 2480 | 3385| 0.130 | 0.130 | 0.138 | 0.138 | 0.136|
```

Above is for a single dict, but eventually I want to concat other dictionaries (with the same structure) as columns to the right of my_dict_A (different version of dict) and rows (new row each time the api returns data).

Should be easy right? All help appreciated...

Comment: In pandas each column has its own heading. Your output seems to have 3 columns to each heading. I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: Thanks jpp. I can add headings above each column (Tier 2 headings) but would want to keep the headings in the tier above (Tier 1) as well. I would hope use: `pd.concat([df_a,df_b],axis=1,keys=['a','b'],names=['Tier 1','Tier2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the order of the data you have to use an `OrderedDict`.
For csv you have to have the same number of seperators.
Lets asume you have `my_dict_A` and `,` as the csv seperator.

```
def no_columns(a_dict=None):
    no = 0
    for v in a_dict.values():
        no += len(v)
    return no

def header(a_dict=None, title=''):
    return title + (len(a_dict) * no_columns(a_dict) -1) * ','

def sub_header(a_dict=None):
    subheader = ''
    for k, v in a_dict.items():
        subheader += k + len(v) * ','
    return subheader

my_header = header(my_dict_A, 'A')
my_sub_header = sub_header(my_dict_A)
```

Note: This will put the headers in the first column of each entry, not in the middle as you have shown it.
I have not tested this code. If there is one `,` to much in the subheader, use `return subheader[:-1]`.